# Excel - enter time duration in mm:ss.00 format (without hrs or colons)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet that I can record times for competitors competing in an event. I need to show `mm:ss.00` and I would love to be able to do this without entering in colons or hours.

I have tried this code in VBA and it works great however it only shows `mm:ss` not the split seconds. Does anyone know how I could edit this code to include the split seconds?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Intrsct As Range, Cell As Range, s As String
    Dim mins As Long, secs As Long, t As Date

    Set Intrsct = Intersect(Range("G13:G104"), Target)
    If Intrsct Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each Cell In Intrsct
            s = Cell.Text
            If s = "" Then
                Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
            ElseIf Len(s) > 4 Then
                Cell.Clear
                Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
             Else
                s = Right("0000" & s, 4)
                If s Like "####" Then
                    mins = CLng(Left(s, 2))
                    secs = CLng(Right(s, 2))
                    t = TimeSerial(0, mins, secs)
                    Cell.NumberFormat = "[mm]:ss"
                    Cell.Value = t
                Else
                    Cell.Clear
                    Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your cells with the following custom format `00\:00\.00`.

[image: Results - mm:ss.00 without hrs or colons]

Comment: Be careful. This is only a cosmetic change. The number in the cell is exactly what you wrote there, it does not represent time.  So `01:00:00 - 00:00.01 = 00:99:99` instead expected `00:59:99`

Comment: @Lluser Yes. If the OP wants to do calculation, the format must be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [`TimeSerial` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timeserial-function) accepts only integer values as its parameters, so the split seconds cannot by passed here. Same is valid for [worksheet function `TIME`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457)

But time is represented as number in this format:

`Hours/24 + Minutes/(24*60) + Second/(24*60*60)`

So if you get this number, you can use your custom format with second fraction for it! (In the screenshot `mm:ss.00` is used)

[image]

See [an example Excel Online file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArVkYVSHnABFiij3VD1wS6Qz0Ldv?e=lWL4Pk) showing the difference between time values generated by `TIME` function and custom formula. (Unfortunately, Excel online does not support creating a custom number format and only `mm:ss.0` is available there.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not show the split seconds you enter because you do not allow it to.

As written, your macro can only have a value output if you entered four or less characters in the cell.

More than four, the macro clears the entry.

Four or less, it creates a time entry in the cell.

Notice that the entry will be minutes (the left two characters) and seconds (the right two characters) made from a four or less character `s`.

So if you actually do enter the split seconds, the entry gets cleared and no time is placed there.

Worse, the `TimeSerial()` creation step makes sure the result is ONLY `mm:ss`.

You need to revisit how to treat you entry string. You must pass at least six characters into the final steps.

To avoid any limitations mentioned with `TimeSerial()`, perhaps do the steps already there, though using the left two characters and the mid third and fourth characters of your string to create the `TimeSerial()` value, then add the right two characters (divided by `(24*60*60*100)` so it actually IS split seconds being added.

Or just take the string dividing each component by the appropriate divisor (minutes:  `(24*60)` and seconds:  `(24*60*60)`), place the value in the cell, and apply the `mm:ss.00` formatting. Excel itself is happy to allow up to thousandths to be shown (`mm:ss.000`).